# Providing links to test outputs in TestNG reports

Tags: report, testng

In my tests, I capture the output of each test and save them as html files in a directory. How can I provide a link to these outputs for each test in the TestNG reports?

e.g. if there is a failure recorded in testNG results, it will also provide the link to the saved html files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where and how you want to report the results. It sounds like you want to create a custom TestNG report that will contain information on the status as well as link to the file generated. There are two main ways to accomplish this in TestNG:

1. Create a test listener - implements [org.testng.ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html), reports status of every tests immediately after tests is executed.
2. Create a test reporter - implements [org.testng.IReporter](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html), provides a consolidated result of the test statuses, when all the tests were executed.

You can refer to [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners) web site for some examples on listeners.